# Windows Function Changes values when called from EF.NET Core

Tags: sql-server

I am having one issue I am using the Rank Function in a Stored Procedure.

When I execute the stored procedure then it returns the correct rank but when I call it from .NET EF Core it changes altogether.

This is the SQL query:

```
select * from ( Select Id, Rank(over order By id) rank from table )vt order by vt.rank desc
```

The EF.Net Core code:

```
var result = _context.model.fromsql("spName").ToListAsync()
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Could you share the routine code?

Comment: SQL : 
select * from (
         Select Id, Rank(over order By id) rank from table
)vt order by vt.rank desc


EF.Net Core:
var result = _context.model.fromsql("spName").ToListAsync()

Comment: Do you have duplicate `Ids`?

Comment: Yes , may have matching ids

Comment: And could you give of example with few records returned on DB and on .net app - how the ranks have changed.

Comment: Is `Id` a date/time/datetime column (or string representing a date/time/datetime) that you're casting in the rank's order by clause? Different settings between SSMS and EF.Core such as [DATEFIRST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql), [DATEFORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql) or [LANGUAGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-language-transact-sql) could lead to different rank results for the same data set.